# getting COPY failed: stat app/dist/out: file does not exist when building angular docker container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

that is Dockerfile configuration

```
FROM node:13-alpine as build-nodejs

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/
ARG build_command=build_prod
RUN npm run ${build_command} -- --output-path=./dist/out

# Final nginx container
FROM nginx:1.13

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y install nginx-extras libnginx-mod-nchan

RUN rm -f etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default \
    && rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
    && rm -f /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=build-nodejs /app/dist/out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I'm getting error
**Step 12/15 : COPY --from=build-nodejs /app/dist/out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat app/dist/out: file does not exist**

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the `npm run` step is not creating the output as expected.

Try building with the `--progress plain` option. This prevents the concatenation of the output and you should be able to see the complete output of that step and check for issues.